# What species is this orange and black caterpillar from Costa Rica?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, lepidoptera, arthropod

[image]
Does anyone know what type of caterpillar this is? I don't know much about them. Pictured it in January in Costa Rica cloudforest (Monteverde) and am using it in a speech for visiting Costa Rica.

Size about 3,5-4 inches.

Comment: This looks like a caterpillar.

Comment: Millipedes and centipedes have chitin segments.  millipedes actually have anywhere from 40 to 400 legs. centipedes have between 15 and 177.

Comment: Looks like a caterpillar in the [Saturniidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturniidae) family

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is [Cricula silkmoth](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=Cricula+silkmoth) (Cricula trifenestrata, Saturniidae), in [caterpillar stage](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=Cricula%20trifenestrata%20caterpillar).

Comment: but this is from costa rica? Cricula trifenestrata is found from India to the Philippines, Sulawesi, Java, and Sri Lanka.

Comment: Similar, but not the same. Cricula trifenestrata had white hairs coming out of the red bulbs. The picture above has black, branched hairs.